# Proving the Trig Identity $e^{i \alpha} + e^{i \beta} = 2e^{i(\alpha + \beta)/2}\cos((\alpha-\beta)/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

We're having trouble proving this trig identity:

$$e^{i \alpha} + e^{i \beta} = 2e^{\frac{i(\alpha + \beta)}{2}}\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$$

---

We've tried various manipulations using basic trig identities (too lengthy to show here) and come up with nasty equations that don't lead anywhere.

Can you point us in the right direction?

Comment: I assume $\alpha, \beta$ are real.

Comment: @N.S. yes, they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show that

$$\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta)+i[\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\beta)]= 2 [\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})+i \sin (\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})]\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}) \,.$$

Identify the real and imaginary parts, and use the formulas for $\cos(x)\cos(y)$ and $\sin(x) \cos(y)$ respectively...

Alternately, you can use that $\alpha=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$ and
$\beta=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the fact that $\cos((\alpha-\beta)/2)=\frac{\exp(i(\alpha-\beta)/2)+\exp(-i(\alpha-\beta)/2)}{2}$ lots of things cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Just work on the right side, it is easy to show using definition of cosine over the complex numbers:

$$cos(z)=\frac {e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$